# Changing the value of a member vector variable in a member function

Tags: c++, class, vector

A have a function in my class that looks something like this:

```
void SomeClass::SomeFunction(int i, int j){

    float var = MemberVector[i][j];
    float temp;
    temp = var * -1;
 ~~~Some Condition~~~{
        MemberVector[i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

I want to get the value at [i][j] in the vector member variable, and multiply it by -1, i.e. make it positive if it is negative and vice verse.

I thought that the vector operator[] returns a reference to the value a the position specified inside the square brackets, but when I run my code it isn't change the values in the member vector variable.

Is there a way to refer to get value at [i][j] in the member variable by reference inside a member function and change it as I describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write something like

```
int x = y;
```

then `x` is a copy of `y`. Changing `x` will *not* change `y`.

To do that, you need a reference, like this

```
int &x = y;
x = 42; // now y is also 42
```

In your case, you don't even really need a reference. You could just modify the element directly,

```
MemberVector[i][j] *= -1;
```

Comment: ok thank you- this works, but I think the bug must be elsewhere- my initial approach also seems ok, if somewhat less neat